# What is "Yale Key, 10½ Section, change 900"

Tags: mechanical-engineering

The specs say:

> Admittance shall be by means of a
>   locked door and/or key operated switch,
>   which in order to provide compatibility
>   within Local Authorities, shall be a **Yale
>   Key, 10½ Section, change 900**. Access to
>   level 1 facilities shall be gained without
>   opening the main controller door(s).

What exactly is the meaning of the bolded section? I guess it defines *some* kind of key (and associated lock), but how do I read it? How can I even begin searching for a lock fulfilling these specs?

Comment: [Yale](http://www.yalelock.com/en/yale/com/) is a manufacturer of locks. You should ask them what the rest of it means.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Generally, Yale type lock is not necessarily manufactured by Yale. You have various types like Mortise, Warded, Wafer tumbler, Tubular locks - and Pin tumbler locks, AKA Yale type locks. Although I bet guys at Yale should know.

Comment: K900 is the cutting punch but I suspect "change900" refers to the number of bitting combinations.   some info at http://www.lsamichigan.org/Tech/Yale%20KeyMark%20Service%20Manual%2042250_5-11RE.pdf

Comment: Is this from the TOPAS UK-traffic signal controller?  That one says "Yale Key Type 900"  http://www.topasgroup.org.uk/MyFiles/Files/specifications/2500A%20v3%20170315.pdf   However, given the complete lack of hits elsewhere on the web,  I suspect this is a spec that's been copied for at least 15 years from previous documents without anyone checking to see whether it makes sense.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: It's that document, though the source was different. I agree, at the time of its writing the idea of touchscreen devices with network access was alien to the authors. We're in the process of estimating costs of adapting our controller to UK specs; things like how much work will be needed to cripple the fine-grained security into the 5 levels required, or how to constrict the versatile access methods to "on-site terminal only"...